# Number of commits and offset in each partition of a kafka topic

Tags: apache-kafka

How to find the number of commits and current offset in each partition of a *known* kafka topic. I am using kafka *v0.8.1.1*

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It is not clear from your question, what kind of offset you're interested in. 
There are actually three types of offsets:

1. The offset of the first available message in topic's partition. Use -2
   (earliest) as --time parameter for GetOffsetShell tool
2. The offset of the last available message in topic's partition. Use -1(latest) as --time
   parameter.
3. The last read/processed message offset maintained by
   kafka consumer. High level consumer stores this information, for every consumer group, in
   an internal Kafka topic (used to be Zookeeper) and takes care about
   keeping it up to date when you call commit() or when auto-commit
   setting is set to true. For simple consumer, your code have to take
   care about managing offsets.

In addition to command line utility, the offset information for #1 and #2 is also available via SimpleConsumer.earliestOrLatestOffset().

If the number of messages is not too large, you can specify a large --offsets parameter to GetOffsetShell and then count number of lines returned by the tool. Otherwise, you can write a simple loop in scala/java that would iterate all available offsets starting from the earliest.

[From Kafka documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/System+Tools):

```
Get Offset Shell
get offsets for a topic
bin/kafka-run-class.sh kafka.tools.GetOffsetShell

required argument [broker-list], [topic]
Option Description 
------ ----------- 
--broker-list <hostname:port,..., REQUIRED: The list of hostname and hostname:port> port of the server to connect to. 
--max-wait-ms <Integer: ms> The max amount of time each fetch request waits. (default: 1000) 
--offsets <Integer: count> number of offsets returned (default: 1)
--partitions <partition ids> comma separated list of partition ids. If not specified, will find offsets for all partitions (default) 
--time <Long: timestamp in milliseconds / -1(latest) / -2 (earliest) timestamp; offsets will come before this timestamp, as in getOffsetsBefore  > 
--topic <topic> REQUIRED: The topic to get offsets from.
```

Comment: I need two functionality
1. Monitor lag for each partition
2. In case of a complete system reboot (zookeeper, broker, producer and consumer), how can I resume from last read/processed message offset in High Level consumer

Answer (score 18):

Regarding the offset of the topic and partition you can use [kafka.tools.GetOffsetShell](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/System+Tools). For example using these command (I have topic `games`):

```
bin/kafka-run-class.sh kafka.tools.GetOffsetShell --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic games --time -1
```

I will get `games:0:47841` which means that for topic `games` and `0` partition I have latest not used offset `47841` (latest available message).

You can use `-2` to see the first available message.

Comment: One caveat: This won't be accurate if log compaction is turned on.

Comment: is there any way to get this same value programmatically?

Answer (score 5):

Starting version 0.9.0.x you should start to use the *kafka.admin.ConsumerGroupCommand* tool. Below are the arguments that the tool take

```
List all consumer groups, describe a consumer group, or delete consumer group info.
Option                                  Description
------                                  -----------
--bootstrap-server <server to connect   REQUIRED (only when using new-
  to>                                     consumer): The server to connect to.
--command-config <command config        Property file containing configs to be
  property file>                          passed to Admin Client and Consumer.
--delete                                Pass in groups to delete topic
                                          partition offsets and ownership
                                          information over the entire consumer
                                          group. For instance --group g1 --
                                          group g2
                                        Pass in groups with a single topic to
                                          just delete the given topic's
                                          partition offsets and ownership
                                          information for the given consumer
                                          groups. For instance --group g1 --
                                          group g2 --topic t1
                                        Pass in just a topic to delete the
                                          given topic's partition offsets and
                                          ownership information for every
                                          consumer group. For instance --topic
                                          t1
                                        WARNING: Group deletion only works for
                                          old ZK-based consumer groups, and
                                          one has to use it carefully to only
                                          delete groups that are not active.
--describe                              Describe consumer group and list
                                          offset lag related to given group.
--group <consumer group>                The consumer group we wish to act on.
--list                                  List all consumer groups.
--new-consumer                          Use new consumer.
--topic <topic>                         The topic whose consumer group
                                          information should be deleted.
--zookeeper <urls>                      REQUIRED (unless new-consumer is
                                          used): The connection string for the
                                          zookeeper connection in the form
                                          host:port. Multiple URLS can be
                                          given to allow fail-over.
```

To get offsets for a Topic_X for a consumerGroup_Y use the command as below

```
bin/kafka-run-class.sh kafka.admin.ConsumerGroupCommand --zookeeper <zookeeper urls> --describe --group consumerGroup_Y
```

Response would look like

```
GROUP, TOPIC, PARTITION, CURRENT OFFSET, LOG END OFFSET, LAG, OWNER
consumerGroup, Topic_X, 0, 3030460, 3168412, 137952, none
consumerGroup, Topic_X, 1, 3030903, 3168884, 137981, none
consumerGroup, Topic_X, 2, 801564, 939540, 137976, none
consumerGroup, Topic_X, 3, 737290, 875262, 137972, none
consumerGroup, Topic_X, 4, 737288, 875254, 137966, none
consumerGroup, Topic_X, 5, 737276, 875241, 137965, none
consumerGroup, Topic_X, 6, 737290, 875251, 137961, none
consumerGroup, Topic_X, 7, 737290, 875248, 137958, none
consumerGroup, Topic_X, 8, 737288, 875246, 137958, none
consumerGroup, Topic_X, 9, 737293, 875251, 137958, none
consumerGroup, Topic_X, 10, 737289, 875244, 137955, none
consumerGroup, Topic_X, 11, 737273, 875226, 137953, none
```

Comment: Has anyone sorted out yet how to modify the offsets using `bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh` with `--command-config` with newer kafka 0.10.x?

Answer (score 2):

This information was also helpful in creating a script to view the number of messages on a partition for a topic (from the command line). While tools like Kafka-Web-Console are nice, some of us live in a non-GUI world.

Here is the script ... use and modify it at your own risk :-)

```
#!/bin/bash

topic=$1

if [[ -z "${topic}" ]] ; then

    echo "Usage: ${0} <topic>"
    exit 1

fi


if [[ -z "${KAFKA_HOME}" ]] ; then

    # $KAFKA_HOME not set, using default /kafka
    KAFKA_HOME="/kafka"

fi

if [ ! -d ${KAFKA_HOME} ] ; then

    echo "\$KAFKA_HOME does not point to a valid directory [$KAFKA_HOME]"
    exit 1

fi

cd $KAFKA_HOME

echo
echo "Topic: ${topic}: "

#
printf "Partition  Count\n"
printf "~~~~~~~~~~ ~~~~~~~~~~~~\n"

idx=0
for msg in `bin/kafka-run-class.sh kafka.tools.GetOffsetShell --topic ${topic} --broker-list localhost:9092 --time -1` ; do

    name=`echo ${msg} | awk -F ":" '{print $1}'`
    partition=`echo ${msg} | awk -F ":" '{print $2}'`
    total=`echo ${msg} | awk -F ":" '{print $3}'`

    printf "%10d %12d\n" ${partition} ${total}
    idx=$((idx + 1))

done

if [ ${idx} -eq 0 ] ; then

    echo "Topic name not found!"
    exit 1

fi

echo
exit ${rc}
```

Comment: The latest offset of each partition doesn't necessarily equal how many messages are currently in each partition due to log retention. If log compaction isn't turned on, you can achieve that count by subtracting the earliest offset from the latest.

Answer (score 2):

Say suppouse we have topic by name tomorrowis27
And our requirment is
Req 1: Wanted to know the partition and offset details of the topic.
Ans : We can use GetOffsetShell command as shown in the below screenshot.

Req 2: Wanted to know the no of offset consumed by a consumer group.
Ans: We can use ConsumerGroupCommand as shown in the below screenshot.

[image: For Req 1 GetOffsetShell command.For Req 2 ConsumerGroupCommand]