# Duplicate offsets in a Kafka topic with more than one partition

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am using `kafka_2.10-0.10.0.1` with `zookeeper-3.4.10`. I know that there are many types of offsets. I have two questions:
- I want to know the type of the offset returned by `ConsumerRecord.offset().`
- If I use a topic created with 10 partitions, can I obtain a set of records with the same offset value? In my program, I need to obtain a list of records with different offset values. I want to know do I have to use a topic with a single partition to achieve this goal?

Comment: Many types of offsets? What do you mean?

Comment: I read that there are offsets stored in Zookeeper and others stored in Kafka broker...

Comment: If you're using a client that's not pre 0.10 (your version of Kafka) it should store its offsets in Kafka. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41137281/offsets-stored-in-zookeeper-or-kafka. Anyway, your client should be storing its offsets in either ZK or Kafka. It would be bad if it was both.

Comment: There are actually three types of offsets. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27499277/number-of-commits-and-offset-in-each-partition-of-a-kafka-topic

Comment: Do you have an answer for my second question please?

Comment: Oh in that sense. I’ve never heard those called types of offsets. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to know the type of the offset returned by `ConsumerRecord.offset()`.

This is the offset of the record within the topic-partition the record came from.

> If I use a topic created with 10 partitions, can I obtain a set of records with the same offset value?

Yes, you can seek to that offset in each partition and read the value. To do this, assign the topic-partitions you want to your consumer with [`Consumer#assign()`](https://kafka.apache.org/0100/javadoc/index.html?org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html), then use `Consumer#seek()` to see to the offset you want to read. When you `poll()`, the consumer will start reading from that offset.

> I want to know do I have to use a topic with a single partition to achieve this goal?

You don't have to do this. You can read whatever offsets you want from whatever partitions you want.

Comment: I do not want to obtain duplicated offsets, that's why I I think to use a topic with a single partition as a solution.

Comment: Each partition has offsets 0 ... infinity. So you'll have offset 123 in each of your partitions. They are not duplicates, because it's actually offset 0-123 (for partition 0), 1-123 (partition 1), etc.

Comment: I reformulate my question: do the offsets start at zero in each partition or continue the offsets of the previous partition.

Comment: Yes, each partition starts with 0. Partitions should be thought of as "parallel". There are no previous or later partitions.

Comment: The fact that partitions are parallel is what enables parallel processing and distribution in Kafka.

Comment: Oh I just understood the phrasing of your original question. Sorry for the confusion. Yes, each partition has its own offsets from 0, but they’re not duplicates.

Comment: If I use one producer which writes in a topic (created with 10 partitions) and a single consumer which reads from it, partitions will be processed in parallel? does the producer writes in partitions in parallel or consecutively (when a partition is full, it uses anothe one)?

Comment: It depends on how you configure the consumer. If it is the only consumer in a consumer group, it will read from all the partitions. Likewise, it depends on how you use the producer. The partition can be explicitly selected, or you can specify a key for the message and the key will be hashed and a partition will be chosen based on the hash. Partitions don't become "full".

Comment: Check out https://kafka.apache.org/0100/javadoc/index.html?org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html and https://kafka.apache.org/0100/javadoc/index.html?org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/KafkaProducer.html and https://kafka.apache.org/0100/javadoc/index.html?org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/ProducerRecord.html

Comment: I put "log.cleaner.enable=false" that's why I think partition may be become "full". In my program, I have one producer and a single consumer which writes and reads from a single topic. The performance is much better when I create the topic with 10 partition than the case when I created with a single partition. I want to understand the reason.