# Kafka connect to read only committed messages

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-connect

We have a kafka Topic that reads messages from transactional producers. We want to set up the kafka connect consumer to read only committed messages.

As I am new to work with Kafka, i need some help from the experts here on setting this up. Based on my initial research, I understand that I need to setup isolation.level = read_committed in our kafka properties.

Now I have the follwoing questions

1. Is this the correct property that I am referring?
2. How can I test after setting this up my Kafka connector is reading only committed messages?
3. Through command line can I see what is the (LSO) Last Stable Offsetid?

We have kafka shell scripts placed inside /confluent/bin folders. My understanding is I need to execute the commands by calling these shell scripts.

Please let me know if any more information required.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Is this the correct property that I am referring?` - Yes

`How can I test after setting this up my Kafka connector is reading only committed messages?` - You can simply write a kafka producer in Java that publishes two messages in two different transactions (m1 in T1 and m2 in T2). Abort transaction T1 and commit transaction T2. In your **read committed** connector, you should see only m2 and not m1.

`Through command line can I see what is the (LSO) Last Stable Offsetid?` - If by stable you mean last read committed offset, I *think* it is not possible. You can get the last offset as explained here: [Number of commits and offset in each partition of a kafka topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27499277/number-of-commits-and-offset-in-each-partition-of-a-kafka-topic)

Comment: Thanks @Rishabh Sharma. i will check this and get back..